# Does .gitattributes need to be on every branch?

Tags: git, gitattributes

As a repo creator/admin I want to ensure that people working on both Windows and Linux won't have problems with line endings (CRLF vs LF). I've read that `.gitattributes` is a good way to do that. I've also read that I need to commit to my repo just like any other file at its root.

But since it's apparently just like any other file do I need to commit it to every branch? Do I need to watch out for this while creating branches (and possibly some other actions)?

I've really tried googling for that but just couldn't find anything.

Comment: Technically, `.gitattributes` isn't "on a branch" or even "in a branch": it's in *commits*. The branch names move and even get deleted; it's the commits that are the solid parts of a repository, and hence the commits that matter. Note that Git automatically de-duplicates otherwise-duplicated files *in* commits, so if the `.gitattributes` contents in ten thousand commits never *changes*, there's really only the one underlying copy, being shared by all the commits.

Comment: Yes, but I either have to make sure this commit is shared by all branches or (less optimal but still possible) have every branch have its own commit with this file.

Comment: Each branch name picks out one commit. That commit—whatever it is—is, by definition, the *last* commit that is "on" that branch. The parent (or parents) of that commit are also on that branch; the parents of the parents are on the branch; and so on. The `.gitattributes` file needs to go into every commit.

Comment: Note that each *new* commit *automatically includes all the files from its parent* unless you explicitly add or remove something. So you generally just create the `.gitattributes` early on, after which it's just automatically in every new commit.

Comment: Ok, got that, thanks. But the bottom line doesn't change - one way or another I have to make sure that `.gitattributes` is included in every commit.

Comment: Right - that's why this is a comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just like `.gitignore` it will only be effective when it's checked out.

Meaning if you check out a branch that doesn't have it then it won't do anything.

But usually that's solved by merging it into `main` or `master` and all other branches will eventually fork from there. If you have any other long-running branches (such as a maintenance branch for an older version), then you can decide to cherry-pick it onto there as well.

Comment: That's what I suspected, thanks. I'll wait before accepting the answer in case others want to add something. ;)

Comment: Technically `.gitattributes` can affect a commit that *isn't* checked out: either because it will be, once the commit gets checked out (so then it affects that future checkout), or when using `git archive`. But overall, yes. :-)